# Read xml using index in NodeJs

Tags: xml, node.js, xml-parsing

Can anyone guide me with how to read/ write XML nodevalues parsed by xml2js.Parser() in 'NodeJS'? So far my code is as flows

```
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var xml = "<body><row><col>firstrow1</col><col>firstrow2</col><col>firstrow3</col></row><row><col>secondrow1</col><col>secondrow2</col><col>secondrow3</col></row></body>";
var extractedData = "";
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
parser.parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    //Extract the value from the data element
    extractedData = result['body']['row']['col[0]'];
    console.log(extractedData);
});
console.log(extractedData);
```

The challenge here is the tag name is same at the data level. How to read it. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

cd your project folder then

> npm install xml2json --save

then in your code

```
var parser = require('xml2json');
var util = require('util'); //for testing

var xmlString = "<body><row><col>firstrow1</col><col>firstrow2</col><col>firstrow3</col></row><row><col>secondrow1</col><col>secondrow2</col><col>secondrow3</col></row></body>";

var object = parser.toJson( xmlString, {object: true});
//printing the result
console.log(util.inspect(object));
```

you can see the documentation of this module [here](https://github.com/buglabs/node-xml2json)